# Styling Form Radio Buttons and Check Boxes

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an HTML form. I want the first label asking a question and the list of *radio buttons* with corresponding labels to appear in one-line. And the second label asking a question and the list of *check boxes* with corresponding labels to appear in one-line. I have posted my code below. Tell me what do I need to add and how to to the styling in CSS.

```css
.jumbotron{
  position:relative;
  background : #000  url(background.jpg) center center;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow:hidden;
  margin-bottom:0px;
} 
.box{
  position:relative;
  background-color:#5DBCD2;
  width:90%;
  margin-top:0.5%;
  height:98.5%;
  margin-bottom:1%;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
}
.navbar{
  min-height: 60px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}
.navbar-inverse{
  background-color:#00FF00;
  border-color:#00FF00;
  font-size:150%;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color:#000000;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size:150%;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover{
  background-color:#800080;
}
#index .navbar-inverse>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.index, #experience .navbar-inverse>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.experience, #video .navbar-inverse>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.video ,#hkust .navbar-inverse>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.hkust ,#feedback .navbar-inverse>.container-fluid>.navbar-collapse>.navbar-nav>.feedback
{
  background-color:#ff69b4;
}
.text
{
  padding-top:0.5%;
  padding-bottom:0.5%;
  text-align: center;
}
.form
{ 
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color:#f4f9a6;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-right:5%;
  width:90%;
  height:80%;
  margin-top:0.5%;
  margin-bottom:1%;
  padding-left:10%;
  padding-right:10%;
  padding-top:10px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <b class="navbar-brand">Vivek's Site</b>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="index"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="experience"><a href="experience.html">Experience</a></li>
        <li class="video"><a href="videos.html">Videos</a></li>
        <li class="hkust"><a href="hkust.html">HKUST Life</a></li>
        <li class="feedback"><a href="feedback.html">Feedback</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="box">
    <div class="text">
      <h1><u>Feedback Form</u></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="form">
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="position">Position:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="position" placeholder="Enter position">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="organization">Organization:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-10"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="organization" placeholder="Enter organization">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="align1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rate">Please rate the site:</label> 
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
              <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1">Excellent</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Very Good</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3" >Good</label>
              </div>      
              <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio4">Fair</label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label><input type="radio" name="optradio5">Poor</label>
              </div>     
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="part">Best Part of Site :</label>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="home">Home</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="experience">Experience</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox ">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="video">Videos</label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox ">
              <label><input type="checkbox" value="hkust">HKUST Life</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="part">Best Aspect of Site :</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="sel1">
            <option>Select</option>
            <option value="content">Content</option>
            <option value="friendly">User-friendliness</option>
            <option value="accessible">Accessibility</option>
            <option value="interactive">Interactivity</option>
            <option value="design">Design</option>
            <option value="time">Load Time</option>
            <option value="compatible">Browser Compatibility</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment">Comments for improvement: </label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group"> 
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Namaste vivek,

here are some of changes i made in your markup, no change in your CSS. Its just about your column structure.

Hope it helps you. You can do the same with checkboxes!

```html
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="rate">Please rate the site:</label> 
    <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <div class="radio col-md-2">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1">Excellent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio col-md-2">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Very Good</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio col-md-2">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3" >Good</label>
        </div>      
        <div class="radio col-md-2">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio4">Fair</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio col-md-2">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio5">Poor</label>
        </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: [Mr.Arjun](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4960784/mr-arjun) - although that's not what i exactly want , thanks a lot. Namastey !

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understood you well, but I did this [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rgqpfLyn/1/) for you.

This is the css I added:

```
/* makes all checkboxes and radio buttons stick to each other */
.radio-container, .radio,
.checkbox-container, .checkbox { 
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.checkbox:last-child, .radio:last-child{
    clear: right;
    display: block;
}

.control-label {
    display: block;
    float: none;
}

.label {
    display: block;
    clear: left;
    float: left!important;
}
```

and in your html I added the classes defined above in this part:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="label control-label col-sm-2" for="rate">Please rate the site:</label> 
    <div class="radio-container col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10"> 
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1">Excellent</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Very Good</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3" >Good</label>
        </div>      
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio4">Fair</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio5">Poor</label>
        </div>     
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <label class="label control-label col-sm-2" for="part">Best Part of Site :</label>
    <div class="checkbox-container col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="home">Home</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="experience">Experience</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox ">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="video">Videos</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox ">
      <label><input type="checkbox" value="hkust">HKUST Life</label>
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
  <label class="label control-label col-sm-2" for="part">Best Aspect of Site :</label>
```

Comment: I want the radio buttons to be next to "Please rate the site:" in one line.

Comment: I want the checkboxes to be next to "Best Part of Site :" in one-line

Comment: and everything else below - thanks a lot [1|13v](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4111568/1l13v)

Comment: isn't like that in the fiddle?